# Using JSON for an API Problems

Tags: php, json, api

I'm not really sure how to describe this but here I go. I am currently building a League of Legends website and I'm using SoloMidNets framework for the API. The github can be found here: https://github.com/solomidnet/php-pvp-api

Here's my code:

```
            <?php          

            $summoner = $api->summoner_by_name('na', $_SESSION['input_name']);

            //This is grabbing the JSON information array from the API
            $summoner1 = $api->league('na', $summoner->id);

            var_dump($summoner1);

            echo '<ul>'.'Summoner Name: '.$_SESSION['input_name'].'</ul>';
            echo '<ul>'.'Rank: './*CODE TO GRAB RANK FROM JSON?*/'</ul>';
            echo '<ul>'.'Tier:'./*CODE TO GRAB TIER FROM JSON?*/'</ul>';
            echo '<ul>'.'League Points: './*CODE TO GRAB LEAGUE POINTS FROM JSON?*/'</ul>';
            echo '<ul>'.'Wins: './*CODE TO GRAB WINS FROM JSON?*/'</ul>';
            echo '<ul>'.'Losses: './*CODE TO GRAB LOSSES FROM JSON?*/'</ul>';

            session_destroy();


        ?>
```

The format when I var_dump(); it look's like this: http://pastebin.com/WGKwmSAz

### Quick summary of what I need help with

I would like to know how to call certain elements of my var - `$summoner1`.

Also how would I go about only selecting the part where
`$summoner1->playerName = PLAYERIMSEARCHINGFORDATAONLY;`

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!
Thanks so much for reading :)

Comment: In the meantime the question will close for being too broad... What is a Summoner Name, for example? The dump is far too long to peruse without any clue.

Comment: I think is very clear. He wants to know how to fetch the information of the JSON provided in the pastebin.

Comment: What problems do you encounter accessing the members and arrays, you already have var_dump()'ed the output, just use the variables :S

Comment: Outputting some variables work fine. Other dont, and when I encounter the error it says "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$tier in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\0.LeagueAPI\lookup.php on line 31". Thanks!

Comment: If you got time, use `var_export` instead of `var_dump` and post results again, please. That thing is almost unreadable.

Comment: As @Tomás said prefer var_export to var_dump in this cases, you were lucky I had to test a var_dump formatter, usually I don't even read a dump long as the one you attached. See http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html for directions on writing good question, getting help faster and grow your reputation score. (and, of course http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ViTgxFiZ var_export for you guys. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that `$summoner1` contains your json string you have to decode it **using true as second parameter** to have an associative array.

Then modifiy your code according to your needs.

```
$leagues = json_decode($response, true);

echo "<h1>LEagues</h1>";
foreach ($leagues as $league) {
echo <h2>{$league['name']}</h2>";
    foreach ($league["entries"] as $player) {
    echo "<ul><li>Summoner Name: {$player['playerOrTeamName']} ({$player['playerOrTeamId']})</li>";
        echo <li>'.'Rank: '. $player["entries"]["rank"] . '</li>';
        echo '<li>'.'Tier:'. $player["entries"]["tier"] . '</li>';
        echo '<li>'.'League Points: '.$player["entries"]["leaguePoints"].'</li>';
        echo '<li>'.'Wins: '.$player["entries"]["wins"].'</li>';
        echo '<li>'.'Losses: '.$player["entries"]["losses"].'</li></ul>';
}
```

I've changed the ul nodes to li ones.

Reference: http://www.php.net/json_decode

**Update**: changed the code according to the new data format.

Comment: This is the new code I'm using atm: http://pastebin.com/SUGCV8MY                Error I'm getting now: 
Notice: Undefined index: entries in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\0.LeagueAPI\lookup.php on line 37

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\0.LeagueAPI\lookup.php on line 37

Comment: @Toscan Are you shure of the content of `$response`? Is not the same of the previous code as the error just says that php did not find the entries inner array

Comment: I'm now getting the following error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'tier' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\0.LeagueAPI\lookup.php on line 33
Tier:P  */Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/vziMbas9/*

Comment: @Toscan remove that key!

Comment: I think I managed to fix it. If I do I'll let you know but for know this comment got my thinking! Thanks!!

Comment: The only problem I am having now is displaying int tables it looks like. $league["26800181"]["name"] works since it outputs a "String". But $league["26800181"]["leaguePoints"] is giving me Notice: Undefined index: leaguePoints. Maybe I'm writing it wrong?

Comment: You have to use $league["26800181"]["entries"][0]["leaguePoints"]

Comment: OMG I love you :) I was trying to use [0] somewhere but I guess I never tried it there. Tysm

Comment: The only thing wrong now is that. The $league["26800181"]["entries"][0]["leaguePoints"] is returning someone else's data. And for some reasons is always the same. How do I tell which leaguePoints it grabs? I've tried changing the [0] but same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The $summoner1 is a json array, that can be decoded to a php associative array with :

```
$mySummoner1 = json_decode($summoner1); //will store everything as $key=>$value
```

accessing the value of the array knowing its key is as easy as:

```
$myValue = $mySummoner1['myKey'];
```

Comment: If you decode without second parameter in json_decode to false, it will be decoded to objects rather than arrays so it would not be `$mySummoner1['myKey'];` but `$mySummoner1->myKey;`

Comment: When I use $myValue = $mySummoner1['tiers']; I get this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\0.LeagueAPI\lookup.php on line 32. I've used $mySummoner1->id; And it works. But on other objects it doesn't seem to work and outputs the error again.